# Sybase control center iphone simulator registration failure

Tags: iphone, ios4, sybase, sup

I have created an application in sybase envioronment for iOS application and I deployed the same in Mac OS.

I registered a new device in Sybase Control Center device users, and the same configuration I have given to my iPhone simulator in Mac Sybase settings but it's never getting registered to SCC, always showing the activation status as Pending.

Can anyone help in solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution to my question. The error was not because of any problems with code or the deployment. The problem is windows firewall in SUP server machine is keep on blocking the port that we are trying to communicate with Sybase Control center and the iPhone device.